# long Hungarian umlaut in typewriter

Tags: accents, typewriter, hungarian

An exercise from 'The TeXbook' asks to write "Pál Erdős" in typewriter type.
The difficulty comes that `\H` cannot be used, as the typewriter font contains other symbols (namely a `}`)

The proposed solution is to borrow the accent from another font

```
{\tt P\'al Erd{\bf\H{\tt o}}s}
```

however the output does not have the accent over the `o` but on an space,
as if `Erd\H{}os` was written

The book's solution works with plain TeX but fails with LaTeX

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you using Plain TeX or LaTeX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fonts in the OT1 encoding are those described in the TeXbook, but `\tt` and `\bf` work *very* differently in LaTeX than in Plain TeX. And they're obsolete and deprecated.

If you want to stick with the OT1 encoding, then

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

{\ttfamily P\'{a}l Erd{\rmfamily\bfseries\H{\mdseries\ttfamily o}}s}

\end{document}
```

is the LaTeX counterpart of the TeXbook exercise.

With the T1 encoding it is much easier, because the typewriter type font has the glyph:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

{\ttfamily P\'{a}l Erd\H{o}s}

\end{document}
```

If you also use UTF-8 for inputting the file, then it's even easier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

{\ttfamily Pál Erdős}

\end{document}
```

and the output is identical to the preceding one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.88]{beramono}
\begin{document}

\ttfamily P\'al Erd{\bfseries\H{o}}s 

Pál Erd\textbf{ő}s 

\rmfamily Pál Erd\textbf{ő}s 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The “o” shouldn't be boldface; moreover no trick is needed if the T1 encoding is selected.